# Ramification of the prime at infinity of function fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $K=\mathbb{F}_q(x)$ be a function field and $L = \mathbb{F}_q(X)(\sqrt[n]{f(x)})$ be an extension where $\deg(f) = d$. I want to find what the ramification index at infinity is. If we let $s = (d,n)$ then I am pretty sure the ramification index would be $n/s$. Here is some reasoning:

We can write $f(x) = (1/x)^{-d}u$, where $u$ is a unit. Then $\sqrt[n]{f(x)} = (1/x)^{-d/n}u^{1/n} = (1/x^{s/n})^{-d/s} u^{1/n}$. Hence $ord_{P_\infty}(\sqrt[n]{f(x)}) = -d/s$. So $ord_{P_\infty}(f(x)) = -nd/s = n/s* ord_{1/x}(f(x)) $. Thus $e=n/s$.

My question is, is this correct? Why would $P_\infty$, the prime lying over $1/x$, be $1/x^{s/n}$ and not $1/x^{1/n}$? Further, I think whether the prime splits or is inert is captured in the leading coefficient of $f(x)$ (i.e. whether it is a $n^th$ root or not). Is this true? What are the exact conditions?

Any solution or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following MAGMA code can be helpful to do very explicit computations of the ramification of the infinite place (http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) : $$ $$   R<x> := FunctionField(GF(5));
P<y> := PolynomialRing(R);
n := 8;
d := 4;
F<alpha> := FunctionField(y^n - x^d - 1);
F;
MF := MaximalOrderFinite(F);
MI := MaximalOrderInfinite(F);
Basis(MF);
Basis(MI);

print "";
Places(F,1);

print "";
P := Places(FunctionField(GF(5)), 1);
inf := P[1];
inf;
DecompositionType(F, inf);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would the prime lying over $1/x$ be $1/x^{s/n}$ and not $1/x^{1/n}$?

If you adjoin $\sqrt[n]{x^n}$ can we even achieve a $1/x^{1/n}$ element? What about, say, $\sqrt[4]{x^2}$: can we obtain an element $1/x^{1/4}$ in this case? This is why $s={\rm gcd}(n,d)$ matters. According to the valuation, we're essentially adjoining $x^{d/n}$ (modulo things of valuation $0$, namely $u^{1/n}$), so if the value group was originally $\Bbb Z$ the new value group is $\Bbb Z+\frac{d}{n}\Bbb Z$. We can apply Bezout's lemma to see the value group is $\frac{1}{n}(n\Bbb Z+d\,\Bbb Z)=\frac{1}{n}(s\Bbb Z)=\frac{1}{n/s}\Bbb Z$ and so the ramification is in fact equal to $e=n/s$.

Not sure about $u\in K^\times$ and inertness though.